# Getting run time error exit code 1 in this code which gives correct output and is within memory and time constraint

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error, exit-code

Below written code works perfectly fine in VSC, however while submitting it in codeforces I am getting run-time error exit code 1.

Problem link : https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1326/B

```
    #include<stdio.h>


     void main()
     {
        int n;
        scanf("%d\n",&n);
        int b[n],a[n],max=0,i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        }
        a[0]=b[0];
        a[1]=b[1]+a[0];
        max=a[1]>a[0]?a[1]:a[0];
        for(i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=b[i]+max;
            max=a[i]>max?a[i]:max;
         }
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
             printf("%d ",a[i]);

    }
```

For the custom input :

```
5

0 1 1 -2 1
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 0 3
```

Runtime error: exit code is 1

Used: 31 ms, 0 KB

Comment: Define `main` properly and see what you get http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: From the link: ***Input** The first line contains one integer n (3≤n≤200000).* So you are making some giant arrays `int b[n] ,a[n]` on the stack (probably). Please use `malloc` instead.

Comment: @jiveturkey you are right to say the definition is incorrect, but this will not cause a run-time fault.

Comment: It seems there are multiple test cases, not just one test case, so the code needs to be in a loop, perhaps until EOF.

Comment: since the  `int b[n],a[n]` arrays are only allocated once, They should be allocated with an initial size of the max size I.E. 10^9 entries.  This means they must be allocated in the heap.  I.E. via `malloc()` or `calloc()`

Comment: regarding: `max=a[1]>a[0]?a[1]:a[0];`   This should be: `max = (a[1] > a[0])? a[1] : a[0];`  Notice the use of the parens around the condition.  Similar considerations exist for: `max=a[i] > max?a[i]:max;`, etc.  Otherwise the decision is based solely on the contents of the single variable immediately before the `?`

Comment: regarding: *run-time error exit code 1.*  this is (probably) from the compiler used by the test site from the statement: `void main()`  Strongly suggest using: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 0):

As input can be very large, the program results in segmentation fault when the value of `n` given is very large. Do not statically allocate arrays `a` and `b`, instead use malloc function to allocate memory

```
int *a, *b;
a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Also, declare main as `int main` and return 0 at the end, instead of `void main`

Comment: Never cast malloc function

Comment: Thank you. It worked after I declared main as int main with return type 0. But why didn't void main work?

Comment: probably because the test site is using a modern compiler, not visual studio nor visual C.